# Can we assign a value to pointer unsigned char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, tetris

Hello everyone I'm trying to make a Tetris game with C++. I'm looking [that tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OK8_tHeCIA&list=WL&index=6&t=405s)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int nFieldWidth = 12;
int nFieldHeight = 18;
unsigned char *pField = nullptr;   //dynamic memory allocation for store game area elements

int main(){
...

pField = new unsigned char[nFieldHeight * nFieldWidth]; 
for(int x = 0; x < nFieldWidth; x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < nFieldHeight; y++)
        pField[y*nFieldWidth+x] = (x == 0 || x == nFieldWidth - 1 || y == nFieldHeight - 1) ? 9 : 0;
...
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

What are we doing in this conditional branching? I know that

```
if(x == 0 || x == nFieldWidth -1 || y == nFieldHeight -1)
   pField[y*nFieldWidth+x] = 9;
else
   pField[y*nFieldWidth+x] = 0;
```

Are we allocating memory? If we are why we set to *9* , in the global we choose 12 and 18 as a border length??

Comment: 12 and 18 are the dimensions of the board. 0 and 9 indicate whether a cell is a boundary cell or not.

Comment: There's no memory allocation done at that point, no.

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to do something crazy like change `? 9 : 0` to `? 0:  9` and see what happens. (Not in production code of course; this is for your own experimentation.)

Comment: why 0 and 9 for the boundary cell? @cigien

Comment: What makes you think memory is being allocated there? Memory was allocated on the line `pField = new unsigned char[nFieldHeight * nFieldWidth];`. This is just filling in the array elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He explains it from 8:20 onward in the youtube video: `pField` is set to 0 if the slot is empty, otherwise 1 to 8 if it is occupied by one of the tetromini shapes. 9 is reserved for the board walls.
So with that ternary condition he is initialising the board, setting it to empty (0) almost everywhere, unless the loop hits the edges (`0` is the left edge, `nFieldWidth - 1` is the right edge, `nFieldHeight - 1` is the bottom edge), where he will place a wall slot (9) instead.

Comment: actually 7 tetromino shapes we have?

Comment: @unamattina: I see, probably number 9 represents the walls because it is opposite (most distant) from 0 which is empty space.
It is conceptually easier to remember that empty and wall are 0-9, then actual pieces can be any number inbetween.